# NGINX upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am getting this error in the logs.
`[error] 117#117: *16706 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream`.I have tried every possible way to check from where i am getting this exact 60s timeout.

I'll add more detail of how i am producing this error in details also (if needed). I don't see any timeout when I run the dotnet api (dockerized) locally.
That API runs for more then 5 minutes but here in AKS cluster it gets timeout in exactly 60s.

So i am using these headers in my config map (for nginx ingress controller).I have checked it by removing and adding these headers one by one but no change in that timeout.

```
  client-header-timeout: "7200"
  keep-alive: "300"
  keep-alive-requests: "100000"
  keepalive-timeout: "300"
  proxy-connect-timeout: "7200"
  proxy-read-timeout: "7200"
  proxy-send-timeout: "7200"
  upstream-keepalive-requests: "100000"
  upstream-keepalive-timeout: "7200"
```

And i have also tried adding these headers in my ingress resource/rule for that microservice.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-header-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 5000m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/keep-alive: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/keepalive-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/large-client-header-buffers: 64 128k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 5000m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 16k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/send_timeout: "7200"
```

Nginx ingress controller version:

```
  Release:       v1.0.5
  Build:         7ce96cbcf668f94a0d1ee0a674e96002948bff6f
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.9
```

We are using Azure Kubernetes cluster and The core dns is resovling all the api/url from an active directory which is deployed in an Azure windows Virtual machine.

Backend API in in dotnet core `(sdk:6.0.400 and ASP.NET core Runtime 6.0.8)` (all the keepalives and request-timeouts settings are already tested that are defined in the code).

Comment: And Kubernetes Version is 
1.22.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. May be i have missed something but seems these

```
proxy-read-timeout: "7200"
proxy-send-timeout: "7200"
```

headers doesn't effect the timeouts for the backend GRPC communication.
I had to add the "server-snippet" to add these

```
grpc_read_timeout 120s; grpc_send_timeout 120s; client_body_timeout 120s;
```

Comment: could you please share your whole server-snippet?

Comment: nevermind, I'm just stupid. I was editing my Deployment manifest instead of my Ingress one.

Comment: Adding it here anyway :)


`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      grpc_read_timeout 120s;
      grpc_send_timeout 120s;
      client_body_timeout 120s;`